# How to animate change of colour (keyframes) forward and back on click with useState without starting animation during first loading of page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, state, css-animations

I got a little tricky problem.

I am having a container with is being coloured on clicking it.
Clicking it will result in sending data to array, but thats not the problem.

Clicking it will also animate the change of colour. Animation will be triggered forward on click, and backwards if container will be clicked again.

The issue is that animation is triggered conditionally with use of useState (boolean) and thus, the second animation will be running already when page is loaded, before even clicking the container.
I was wondering about animation-play-state style, but it not seems to be sufficient.

Heres the editable demo https://qeevsk.csb.app/
Any ideas, maybe there is better aproach ?

The code itself:

```
    const [activeDiv, setDivState] = useState(false);
    
      const BigDiv = styled("div")(
        ({ theme, activeDiv }) => css`
          min-width: 220px;
          height: 100%;
          position: relative;
          padding: ${theme.spacing(2, 0)};
          border-bottom: red 4px solid;
          background-color: transparent;
          cursor: pointer;
          text-align: center;
          transition-delay: 0.5s;
        will-change: transform;

    ::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: ${activeDiv ? "red" : "transparent"};
      animation: ${activeDiv ? setColor("red") : unsetColor("red")}
        0.5s ease ;
      transform-origin: bottom center};
    }

    `
  );

  const setColor = (colorTo) => keyframes` 
  0% {transform: scaleY(0); }
  100% {transform: scaleY(1); background-color: ${colorTo}} 
`;
  const unsetColor = (colorFrom) => keyframes`
  0% {transform: scaleY(1); background-color: ${colorFrom}}
  100% {transform: scaleY(0); background-color: transparent;}
 
`;

  const SecondDiv = styled("div")(
    ({ theme, activeDiv, color }) => css`
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
    `
  );

  return (
    <>
      <BigDiv
        activeDiv={activeDiv}
        onClick={(e) => {
          setDivState(!activeDiv);
        }}
      >
        <SecondDiv>
          <p>Click to animate</p>
        </SecondDiv>
      </BigDiv>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got some valid answers already, but if you're looking for a different approach you could manage the animation state with a third value like "IDLE":

```js
const AnimStatus = {
  IDLE: -1,
  INACTIVE: 0,
  ACTIVE: 1
};

// the status will be handled like this:
const [divStatus, setDivStatus] = useState(AnimStatus.IDLE);

  <BigDiv
    divStatus={divStatus}
    onClick={(e) => {
      setDivStatus((prev) =>
        prev === AnimStatus.INACTIVE || prev === AnimStatus.IDLE
          ? AnimStatus.ACTIVE
          : AnimStatus.INACTIVE
      );
    }}
  />
  
// in the css animation
const BigDiv = styled("div")(
  ({ theme, divStatus }) => css`
    /* BigDiv CSS properties */

  ::after {
  /* Other ::after CSS properties */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    ${
      divStatus !== AnimStatus.IDLE
        ? css`
            background-color: ${divStatus === AnimStatus.ACTIVE
              ? "red"
              : "transparent"};
            animation: ${divStatus === AnimStatus.ACTIVE
                ? setColor("red")
                : unsetColor("red")}
              0.5s ease;
          `
        : ""
    }
  };
}
  `
);
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can reuse this `AnimStatus` across all your animations as an interface, and easily add specific effects for "IDLE"

Here is my demo: [https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-divs-forked-u2oltp](https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-divs-forked-u2oltp?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a state variable something like `startAnimation` and set to to false by default.

When user click on `click it to continue` then set it to true and apply animation accordingly

Defined state

```
const [startAnimation, setStart] = useState(false);
```

Pass it in component

```
<BigDiv
        activeDiv={activeDiv}
        startAnimation={startAnimation}
        onClick={(e) => {
          setStart(true);
          setDivState(!activeDiv);
        }}
      >
        <SecondDiv>
          <p>Click to animate</p>
        </SecondDiv>
      </BigDiv>
    </>
```

Use it in component like this

```
const BigDiv = styled("div")(
    ({ theme, activeDiv, startAnimation }) => css`
      min-width: 220px;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      padding: ${theme.spacing(2, 0)};
      border-bottom: red 4px solid;
      background-color: transparent;
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    will-change: transform;

    ::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: ${activeDiv ? "red" : "transparent"};
      animation: ${
        startAnimation ? (activeDiv ? setColor("red") : unsetColor("red")) : ""
      }
        0.5s ease ;
      transform-origin: bottom center};
    }

    `
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix I could think of was to set the initial activeDiv state to `null` and change the animation rule to:

```
animation: ${activeDiv ? setColor("red") : unsetColor("red")} ${activeDiv === null ? "0" : "0.5s ease"} ;
```

Now there won't be any animation at startup, but it will animated if activeDiv is anything but null.

Here is my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/animate-divs-forked-gth814